# Kerberos network security protocol

Tags: security, networking, protocols, kerberos

I am having a real hard time trying to find any information on network security protocols that are similar to the Kerberos protocol. Can anyone provide me with names of similar protocols, or direct to me where there is more information?

kind regards

Comment: *Is* there another network security protocol similar to Kerberos? How similar? Similar how?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of protocols similar to Kerberos, but I am not aware of any implementations in use.  The similarity is that they all use symmetric key cryptography and a trusted server (with whom symmetric keys are shared) to allow other parties (between whom there are no shared secrets) to authenticate each other.  The protocols include:

- [Needham–Schroeder protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham%E2%80%93Schroeder_protocol)
- [Neuman–Stubblebine protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuman%E2%80%93Stubblebine_protocol)
- [Yahalom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahalom_%28protocol%29)
- [Wide Mouth Frog protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Mouth_Frog_protocol)